# C: sharing access to register variables in multiple functions

Tags: c, pointers, global, local, cpu-registers

Currently I am working on a small piece of code for a processor design assignment.

I know it normally would be bad practice, but for this assignment, since we are implementing an extremely specific functionality on a specialized processor, I have decided to make the processor data-memory-less. All data will be only in a FIFO from another processor, or in registers. It fits because the amount of data is small.

Therefore all the variables in my C code have the prefix "register": it tells the compiler to keep them in registers, which works fine.

C, however, does not allow defining global register variables, so all my variables were declared locally in the entry function.

A problem arises when I want to call another function from the entry function, which needs to operate on the same register variables. The second function cannot see them as they are local in the entry function.
I cannot make these variables global (see above), I cannot pass a pointer (since registers aren't addressable), so the only way I saw to do this is to actually pass all the variables to the second function in a struct, have the second function operate on them and return the new values to the first function in another struct.

This seems like a very bad move because I don't think the compiler is smart enough to realize that actually, the second function should simply access the registers of the original variables directly. It results in lots of unneccessary register copying back and forth.

The compiler I'm using does not support nested functions (like GCC). And because this is C, there are no classes possible.

Is there any other (elegant) way to get around this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "I have decided to ***make*** the processor data-memory-less." - so, you are actually fabricating a processor?

Comment: This is very general question. Everything depends on logic of your set of functions. Theoretically you can use one register for bitmask (to inform all functions which registers are busy or free) and all others for data.

Comment: Making your function `inline` might help your compiler figure out the optimization, if that's a possibility. Otherwise, there's always writing this piece of code in assembly language if you really want to make sure the processor does what you want. `register` is a mere hint to the compiler at the best of times, so there's no way in standard C to actually guarantee anything of this nature.

Comment: I am using a processor design package which comes with auto-generated compilers and simulator, so that's what I mean by "making" a processor.

Comment: I find that it does exactly what I want with the register keyword, but it's just a shame I can't declare global variables that way - both of these functions need to access these variables, and passing them seems very nasty.

Comment: My latest solution is to paste one function's code into the other, and use goto's to go back and forth. However, there is no such  thing as addressable labels in this code, so I have had to use a 63-way if statement to select the right goto to "return" with... not very nice either.